# Python: Why am I getting an incorrect syntax message for the comma between 6 and 9 in my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

I am getting an incorrect message between the 6 and the 9 in my dictionary. any ideas?

```
numbers = {
    "threes" : 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99
    "fives" : 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100
    }
print(numbers)
```

Comment: As I understand you want to store a list of numbers. So just do {"key": [number, number]}

Comment: Because you must define those elements of the dictionary as either a list or a tuple.

Comment: And to explain why between 6 and 9 - it assume 6 is a key, so it expects to get semi-colon after 6, but gets comma instead.

Answer (score 1):

In python, if you are creating a value of a dictionary with several arguments, you need to wrap it in parenthesis.

```
numbers = {
    "threes" : (3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99),
    "fives" : (5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100)
    }
print(numbers)
```

Comment: I have just done that and I am now getting an invalid syntax mark on the the air quotes at the start of "fives"

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure you added the comma after the `)` @HectorJames

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't noticed that.